# pull access denied for 8u162-jdk in maven project

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile-maven-plugin

I have a dockerfile in a maven project, and I have this error in the Build when I use the docker base image **8u162-jdk**.

The build works fine when I use **openjdk:8u131-jdk-alpine**, but I need to change JDK version to **8u162**.

```
Step 1/15 : FROM 8u162-jdk

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:03 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-08-23T14:26:57Z
[INFO] Final Memory: 82M/420M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.4.13:build (build-image) on project app-back: Exception caught: pull access denied for 8u162-jdk, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login' -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[Pipeline] error
[Pipeline] step
Recording test results
[Pipeline] }
```

How to resolve this? What is the right image to use when we want to have the version 8u162 of JDK?

Comment: Does your `FROM` line actually contain the word `openjdk`?

Comment: that was my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use one of  `8u222-jdk, 8u222, 8-jdk, 8` tags, see [more](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/)

Comment: I also have this error though: `/bin/sh -c apk update && apk add py-pip curl bash gawk sed grep bc coreutils' returned a non-zero code: 127` 

What sould I replace it with?